# Docker build error on windows 10 "executor failed running..."

Tags: python, docker

How do i solve this? all the packages from (python-telegram-bot ... pyvirtualdisplays) has been installed manually but this still happens...

```
 PS C:\Users\ASUS PC\Documents\GitHub\Telegram-moodle-notification-bot> docker build -t nugas-bot .
 [+] Building 3.0s (12/12) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 32B                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/fedora:latest                                                                                                       2.5s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2.05kB                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => [1/8] FROM docker.io/library/fedora@sha256:9d71386ce04de67b68519d55ca3926cb960a7768d631e6d215eca69b6bb7c2a3                                                        0.0s
 => CACHED [2/8] RUN sudo dnf -y update &&     sudo dnf -y install make wget gcc firefox Xvfb                                                                          0.0s
 => CACHED [3/8] RUN wget http://download.redis.io/redis-stable.tar.gz &&     tar xvzf redis-stable.tar.gz &&     sudo make install -C redis-stable                    0.0s
 => CACHED [4/8] RUN wget https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.26.0/geckodriver-v0.26.0-linux64.tar.gz &&     tar -xvzf geckodriver* &&     ch  0.0s
 => CACHED [5/8] RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash moodle                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => CACHED [6/8] ADD . /usr/local/bin/                                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => CACHED [7/8] RUN chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/entry-point.sh                                                                                                           0.0s
 => ERROR [8/8] RUN pip3 install python-telegram-bot redis selenium walrus pyvirtualdisplay                                                                            0.4s

 > [8/8] RUN pip3 install python-telegram-bot redis selenium walrus pyvirtualdisplay:
 #12 0.374 /bin/sh: line 1: pip3: command not found

 executor failed running [/bin/sh -c pip3 install python-telegram-bot redis selenium walrus pyvirtualdisplay]: exit code: 127
```

I already installed pip3 and python too

```
PS C:\Users\ASUS PC\Documents\GitHub\Telegram-moodle-notification-bot> python -V
Python 3.8.0
PS C:\Users\ASUS PC\Documents\GitHub\Telegram-moodle-notification-bot> pip3 -V
pip 21.3 from c:\users\asus pc\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip 
(python 3.8)
```

> `Blockquote`

Answer (score 1):

You've installed `Python` and `pip` in your computer but *not* on your docker container, the docker container basically behaves as a separate virtual OS and you need to install `python` and `pip` in docker.

To do that add this line to your `Dockerfile` before you call `RUN pip3 install ...`

```
RUN apt-get -y install python3-pip
```

Comment: Okay thanks, your solution works like a charm, but now I have an issue again. After it finished build the images, now when I try to run it in powershell with "docker run --rm -ti nugas-bot" it says "No such file or directory".... what should I do now?

Comment: does the directory nugas-bot exist?